# Query on Java shift operator

Tags: java

What does the following shift operator do in Java?

```
int src1, src2, ans;
ans = src1 >>> src2;
```

Comment: [doc reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). Right shift, shifts 0s in. Shifts `src1` right `src2` bits, stores result in `ans`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a  unsigned right shift operator. More on that here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html